# COBOL report at end of program

Tags: cobol

I am trying to finish a program that I have started but am confused as to what I need to do and how to do the last step.  The instructions are to:

At the end of report:
A. Print the number of personnel records processed.
B. The number of records where there was an unsuccessful search of the Dept Table.
C. The number of records where there was an unsuccessful search of the Title Table.

I have completed all of the program except this last step.  Can someone please help me finish this program?

```
enter code here        ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT PERSONNEL-FILE
            ASSIGN TO 'CH12PPPF.DAT'
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT DEPT-TABLE-FILE
            ASSIGN TO 'CH12PPDT.DAT'
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT TITLE-TABLE-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'CH12PPTT.DAT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT PRINT-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'THORNTONCA4.RPT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  PERSONNEL-FILE.
   01  PERSONNEL-REC.
       05  SSNO-IN             PIC 9(9).
       05  NAME-IN             PIC X(20).
       05  SALARY-IN           PIC 9(6).
       05  CAMPUS-CODE-IN      PIC 9.
       05  DEPT-CODE-IN        PIC 99.
       05  TITLE-CODE-IN       PIC 999.
   FD  DEPT-TABLE-FILE.
   01  DEPT-REC.
       05  T-DEPT-NO           PIC 99.
       05  T-DEPT-NAME         PIC X(10).
   FD  TITLE-TABLE-FILE.
   01  TITLE-REC.
       05  T-TITLE-CODE        PIC 999.
       05  T-TITLE-NAME        PIC X(10).
   FD  PRINT-FILE.
   01  PRINT-REC               PIC X(80).
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  STORED-AREAS.
       05  MORE-RECS           PIC X(3)        VALUE 'YES'.
       05  WS-DATE.
           10  WS-YEAR                     PIC 9999.
           10  WS-MONTH                    PIC 99.
           10  WS-DAY                      PIC 99.
       05  WS-PAGE-CT                      PIC 99
               VALUE ZERO.
       05  WS-LINE-CT                      PIC 99
               VALUE ZERO.
   01  HDR1-OUT.
       05                                  PIC X(25)
               VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(20)
               VALUE 'FINAL REPORT'.
       05  DATE-OUT.
           10  MONTH-OUT                    PIC 99.
           10                               PIC X
              VALUE '/'.
           10  DAY-OUT                      PIC 99.
           10                               PIC X
              VALUE '/'.
           10  YEAR-OUT                    PIC 9999.
       05                                  PIC X(2)
              VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(5)
              VALUE 'PAGE'.
       05  PAGE-OUT                        PIC Z9.


  *****************************************************************
  *  The Campus Table consists of 5 10-position names and will be *
  *    accessed as a direct-referenced table.  EACH_CAMPUS        *
  *    subscriped by the CAMPUS_CODE_IN will provide the name.    *
  *****************************************************************
   01  CAMPUTS-TABLE
         VALUE 'UPSTATE   DOWNSTATE CITY  MELVILLE      HUNTINGTON'.
       05  EACH-CAMPUS
           OCCURS 5 TIMES      PIC X(10).
  *****************************************************************
  * The Dept Table will be accessed by a SEARCH.  Even if the     *
  *    table is entered in Dept No sequence, there would be no    *
  *    real benefit to using a SEARCH ALL since there are only    *
  *    25 entries.                                                *
  *****************************************************************
   01  DEPT-TABLE.
       05  DEPT-ENTRIES OCCURS 25 TIMES INDEXED BY X1.
           10  DEPT-NO         PIC 99.
           10  DEPT-NAME       PIC X(10).
  *****************************************************************
  * The Title Talbe will be accessed by a SEARCH ALL.  To use a   *
  *    binary seach the entries must be in sequence by a key      *
  *    field and the table should be relatively large.            *
  *****************************************************************
   01  TITLE-TABLE.
       05  TITLE-ENTRIES OCCURS 50 TIMES
             ASCENDING KEY IS TITLE-NO INDEXED BY X2.
           10  TITLE-NO        PIC 999.
           10  TITLE-NAME      PIC X(10).
   01  DETAIL-REC.
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  SSNO-OUT            PIC 999B99B9999.
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  NAME-OUT            PIC X(20).
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  SALARY-OUT          PIC $ZZZ,ZZZ.
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  CAMPUS-OUT          PIC X(10).
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  DEPT-OUT            PIC X(10).
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  TITLE-OUT           PIC X(10).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN-MODULE.
       OPEN INPUT  PERSONNEL-FILE
                   DEPT-TABLE-FILE
                   TITLE-TABLE-FILE
            OUTPUT PRINT-FILE
       MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-DATE
       MOVE WS-MONTH TO MONTH-OUT
       MOVE WS-DAY TO DAY-OUT
       MOVE WS-YEAR TO YEAR-OUT
       PERFORM 500-HDG-RTN.
       PERFORM 200-LOAD-DEPT-TABLE
       PERFORM 300-LOAD-TITLE-TABLE
       PERFORM UNTIL MORE-RECS = 'NO '
            READ PERSONNEL-FILE
              AT END
                 MOVE 'NO ' TO MORE-RECS
              NOT AT END
                 PERFORM 400-CALC-RTN
            END-READ
       END-PERFORM
       CLOSE PERSONNEL-FILE
             DEPT-TABLE-FILE
             TITLE-TABLE-FILE
             PRINT-FILE
       STOP RUN.
   200-LOAD-DEPT-TABLE.
       PERFORM VARYING X1 FROM 1 BY 1
                UNTIL X1 > 25
          READ DEPT-TABLE-FILE
            AT END DISPLAY 'NOT ENOUGH DEPT TABLE RECORDS'
                STOP RUN
          END-READ
          MOVE DEPT-REC TO DEPT-ENTRIES (X1)
       END-PERFORM.
   300-LOAD-TITLE-TABLE.
       PERFORM VARYING X2 FROM 1 BY 1
                UNTIL X2 > 50
          READ TITLE-TABLE-FILE
            AT END DISPLAY 'NOT ENOUH TITLE TABLE RECORDS'
                STOP RUN
          END-READ
          MOVE TITLE-REC TO TITLE-ENTRIES (X2)
          IF X2 > 1 THEN
              IF TITLE-NO (X2) <= TITLE-NO (X2 - 1)
                 DISPLAY 'TITLE RECORDS ARE NOT IN SEQUENCE'
                 STOP RUN
              END-IF
          END-IF
       END-PERFORM.
   400-CALC-RTN.
       MOVE SPACES TO DETAIL-REC
       MOVE SSNO-IN TO SSNO-OUT
       MOVE NAME-IN TO NAME-OUT
       MOVE SALARY-IN TO SALARY-OUT
       IF CAMPUS-CODE-IN >= 1 AND <= 5
          MOVE EACH-CAMPUS (CAMPUS-CODE-IN) TO CAMPUS-OUT
       END-IF
       SET X1 TO 1
       SEARCH DEPT-ENTRIES
          AT END MOVE 'XXXXXXXXXX' TO DEPT-OUT
          WHEN DEPT-CODE-IN = DEPT-NO (X1)
            MOVE DEPT-NAME (X1) TO DEPT-OUT
       END-SEARCH
       SEARCH ALL TITLE-ENTRIES
          AT END MOVE 'XXXXXXXXXX' TO TITLE-OUT
          WHEN TITLE-NO (X2) = TITLE-CODE-IN
            MOVE TITLE-NAME (X2) TO TITLE-OUT
       END-SEARCH
       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM DETAIL-REC
           AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES.
   500-HDG-RTN.
       ADD 1 TO WS-PAGE-CT
       MOVE WS-PAGE-CT TO PAGE-OUT
       WRITE PRINT-REC FROM HDR1-OUT
            AFTER ADVANCING PAGE
       MOVE ZEROS TO WS-LINE-CT.
```

Comment: What do you mean "Print the number of personnel records"? as in print to the screen? or to a physical printer? It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to create the layout for a summary record, populate the values and print it. Just like you do for DETAIL-REC but with a different format. You will need to count the records as you read them.

Comment: @AlastairPitts yes it means to print to the screen.  I am sorry about the vague instructions but these are the instructions that were given to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

Produce code to accumulate all the values you need to print at the end
Produce definition(s) of the final part of the report
Produce the final part of report once the main input file has been processed, ie after your first PERFORM and before the CLOSE

You should get into the habit of checking all file statuses after each IO operation, using FILE-STATUS, and accurately report when something unexpected happens.

You'll find it worthwhile to give good names even to indexes, and use 88s wherever possible for IF or EVALUATE and avoid using things like this "IF CAMPUS-CODE-IN >= 1 AND <= 5".